# Unsigned integer arithmetic warnings

Tags: c++, warnings, unsigned-integer, integer-arithmetic

I do apologize if this question has been answered somewhere else, but I've searched, and have not yet found an answer...

I get the following warning when compiling the code below:

```
warning: conversion to 'short unsigned int' from 'int' may alter its value
```

Here is an excerpt of code (several examples to illustrate my question):

```
std::vector<unsigned short int> list = {1}; 
unsigned short int one = 1;

one += list.at(0);                            // produces warning
one += 1;                                     // produces warning
one += static_cast<unsigned short int> 1;     // produces warning
one++;                                        // does not produce warning
```

I've also tried other forms of arithmetic besides addition. Why does the compiler throw this warning, claiming that I'm converting to an 'unsigned short int' from an 'int' (especially when I've explicitly cast it as unsigned)? It would also seem, that for the second case, 'one += 1;', since the right side of the expression is a positive number, the compiler wouldn't have any problem adding it to the unsigned variable 'one'.

Also, the final test, 'one++;' does not produce a warning, and I'm not sure why.

I'm still getting used to asking questions on here, so forgive me if this question is trivial or unclear. Thanks!

Comment: I dont get a warning with g++, what flags are you using?

Comment: Agree no warnings `c++ -Wall`. Maybe paste the exact code.

Comment: I can't see any reason for a warning (you'll get an error with parenthesis around the `1` you static cast though)... no warnings evident with [GCC on ideone](http://ideone.com/CKmX9L) but I'm not sure what warning levels that uses by default.  Which compiler are you using, what settings?

Comment: With g++ it only [pops up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a2c3223513b9772) if you specify `-Wconversion`.

Comment: Actually I just found that warning is not turned by `-Wall` with g++. You need `-Wsign-conversion`, but I still don't get it with the above code (after syntax error is fixed). If you change the `unsigned short` to `int` you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 §5.17/7:

> **”**
>   The behavior of an expression of the form `E1` *op* `= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1` *op* `E2` except that `E1` is
>   evaluated only once

This means that e.g.

```
one += list.at(0);
```

is evaluated *as if* it were

```
one = one + list.at(0);
```

except that `one` is evaluated only once.

In the expresseion `one + list.at(0)` both operands are first promoted to `int`, by C++11 §5/9, the *usual arithmetic conversions* rule.

In short, C++ binary arithmetic operators do not deal with operands of types with potentially smaller range than `int`. The operands are promoted. And then for the final assignment, there is (logical) conversion back down.